# How do I fix my procedure country_demographics?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE country_demographics
  (p_country_name  IN countries.country_name%TYPE,
   p_country_demo_rec  OUT ed_type)
 IS
  TYPE ed_type IS RECORD (
      c_name countries.country_name%TYPE, 
      c_location     countries.location%TYPE, 
      c_capitol countries.capitol%TYPE, 
      c_population countries.population%TYPE, 
      c_airports countries.airports%TYPE, 
      c_climate countries.climate%TYPE);

BEGIN
  SELECT country_name, location, capitol, population, airports, climate
  INTO ed_type.c_name, ed_type.c_location, ed_type.c_capitol, ed_type.population, ed_type.airports, ed_type.climate
  FROM countries;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country Name:' || v_country_demo_rec.country_name || 
          'Location:' || v_country_demo_rec.location || 
          'Capitol:' || v_country_demo_rec.capitol || 
          'Population:' || v_country_demo_rec.population || 
          'Airports:' || v_country_demo_rec.airports || 
          'Climate:' || v_country_demo_rec.climate );

 IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201, 'This country does not exist.');
 END IF;
END;
```

The problem is asking me to create a procedure called `country_demograhics`. Pass the `country_name` as an IN parameter. Display `CONTRY_NAME`, `LOCATION`, `CAPITOL`, `POPULATION`, `AIRPORTS`, `CLIMATE`. Use a user-defined record structure for the INTO clause of your select statement. Raise an exception if the country does not exist.
Now here is a copy of my code, that keeps coming back with an error of:

```
Error at line 0: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated.
```

Comment: ed_type is type not neme of variable... you have to declared  variable e.g : my_record ed_type;

Comment: You cannot use `OUT ed_type` as parameter if `TYPE ed_type` is defined **inside** the procedure. You must define it outside, either in the package or as schema object.

Comment: Are these attributes all columns? If yes, you can simply write `p_country_demo_rec  OUT countries%ROWTYPE` and `SELECT * INTO p_country_demo_rec FROM ...`

Comment: you might want to add a where clause to that select ...into...

Comment: Where and how it's located you statement "IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN" will never evaluate to true. This is because if it would a "NO_DATA_FOUND" exception will have been fired and your statement bypassed. The research the structure of a pl/sql block, for how to handle exceptions.

Comment: You need to work through the compilation errors figuring out why each one occurs. At the moment I'm afraid the question is a bit of an ["It's Not Working"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking) / [Missing Exception](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Answer (score 0):

That error should be the second error which tells you, it will not look any further. There should be another error too. I guess that ed_type doesn't exist outside of the procedure so it can not have an ed_type as OUT parameter. ed_type isn't known outside.

Answer (score 0):

First thing - Look you used the different variable in declaring(p_country_demo_rec ) and begin(v_country_demo_rec) part. I think that might be one mistake.

Try following script:- it may help you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COUNTRY_DEMOGRAPHICS
IS
TYPE ED_TYPE IS TABLE OF countries%ROWTYPE;
p_country_demo_rec  ED_TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO p_country_demo_rec FROM countries;
FOR i IN p_country_demo_rec.FIRST..p_country_demo_rec.LAST 
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country Name:'||p_country_demo_rec(i).country_name || 
      'Location:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).location || 
      'Capitol:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).capitol || 
      'Population:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).population || 
      'Airports:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).airports || 
      'Climate:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).climate );
END LOOP;
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201, 'This country does not exist.');
END IF; 
END;
/

EXECUTE COUNTRY_DEMOGRAPHICS;
```

Note:- You can use the one parameter(IN parameter) in a procedure to get the specific country demographics data and that parameter use in select statement for filter out the specific country.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COUNTRY_DEMOGRAPHICS(p_country_name IN varchar2)
```

Select statement looks like:

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO p_country_demo_rec FROM countries where 
country_name = ||p_country_name;
```

Execute part:

```
EXECUTE COUNTRY_DEMOGRAPHICS(p_country_name);
```